# How to make URL in detailView row

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, detailview

How can I make a **URL** in `DetailView` row on yii2?

For example: blow code is something like custom row in `GridView`, but as you know `DetailView` is different and this code not works in `DetailView`.

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
      'model' => $model,
      'attributes' => [
   [
   'attribute' => 'file',
   'label' => 'File',
   'fomat' => 'Url', // I want something like this
   'value' => Html::a('Dowaload The File', ['files/uloads']),
   ],
])
```

I have not found my problem's solution in similar questions.

Please help me to create `Url` row in **DetailView**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either the shorthand url formatter (that does not provide much customization options):

```
'attributes' => [
  'file:url'
]
```

Or the `raw` format with which you can customize everything:

```
'attributes' =>[
  [
    'attribute'=>'file',
    'label'=>'File',
    'format'=>'raw',
    'value'=>Html::a('Download the File', url),
  ],
...
```

Comment: For the first solution I can't use it, because I want set custom `url`, actually I want make a link for download file.

Comment: For second solution I faced with this error `Use of undefined constant url - assumed 'url'`.

Comment: Where i put `url` yo should put **your** url, the destination for the link

Comment: please vote my question if you like. because I have not seen question like this.

Comment: I think `file:url` will work correctly only if the full paths are saved in the database. or am i wrong

Comment: Well, tecnically it applies the `url` formatter to the field in the model. Usually it's been extracted directly from the db, but not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

You can create a download link to the file inside the detail view in the following way, I am assuming that the file path for download is coming from the database field `file`.

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
      'model' => $model,
      'attributes' => [
         [
         'attribute' => 'file',
         'label' => 'File',
         'value' => function ($model) {
              return Html::a('Download The File', $model->file);
          },
          'format' => 'raw',
         ],
      ]
]);
```